# AWS VPC Route Table -- Delete default route

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

In AWS VPC each route table you create comes with a defualt (local route 10.0.0.0/16) this causes some problem when I want my EC2 instances to have another EC2 instance as default gateway.

For instance if you have two EC2 intances namely A (in subnet 10.0.30.0/24) and B (in subnet 10.0.40.0/24) and if you set A as the default gateway for B then all packets from B are not sent via A. Instead they are sent via 10.0.40.1.

I even tried creating a new route table and add a route like : 0.0.0.0/0 go via NIC of A, even this does not route traffic via A

If I delete the route to 10.0.40.1 on B then I lose all connectivity to B

My questions are:

1. What can I do to make sure all packets from B are always sent via A?
2. Is it possible to delete the 10.0.0.0/16 local route?
3. What else can I do to do what I want?

Comment: 10.0.40.1is a virtual device and will forward all Internet-bound traffic to the instance you configure as the subnet's default route.  That's how VPC does it.  Are you talking about traffic bound for other instances within the VPC, as opposed to Internet traffic?  If so, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes other instances within VPC; I mean all traffic from B no matter where it is destined to must go through A, what that means is if B tries to communicate with another device lets say C (within same VPC) even that traffic I want passed through A. In order to do this I created a new route table and created a route that says 0.0.0.0/0 go via NIC of A but I don't see any traffic between B and C going through A, it instead somehow gets delivered directly to C.

Answer (score 2):

Well. In this case, `A` also needs to have an interface in 10.0.40.0/24 if you want to forward packets through it.  `A` and `B` are in different segments which makes it impossible for one to reach the other at the IP level (Packets are going through a router that you don't control by default).

In essence what this diagram shows:

[image: VPC Description]

I believe you can create this connection with creating a Network Interface in your VPC subnet 10.0.40.0/24 and then attaching it to the Instance in `A`:

[image: Network Interfaces]

Comment: I dont want to make A part of B's network. What I want to achieve is to have three distinct subnets say a, b, and c each with devices A, B and C respectively. I want A to act as a middleman between B and C (in fact any device within b and c subnets). A in my case is a virtual device that I am experimenting with and AWS routing is making it difficult for me.

Comment: So the middle man needs to have interfaces in both `A` and `B`. If you are using linux make sure you turn on forwarding.